# Same XPATH repeating in different divs

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am crawling data from https://www.whatuni.com/university-course-reviews/ and trying to get the rating info for each post. They use exactly the same names for the rating spans. I couldn't find a unique identifier. Example HTML is below how can I get ratings for each uni and department separately? Also, other sub ratings like Job Prospects and Course and Lecturers?

```
<div class="rlst_wrap">
<h2><a href="/university-profile/university-of-chichester/5487/" onclick="viewProfileGaLogging('University of Chichester')" title="University of Chichester">University of Chichester</a></h2>
<h3><a href="/degrees/song-writing-and-cabaret-performance-ba-hons/university-of-chichester/cd/57659274/5487/" title="Song Writing and Cabaret Performance BA (Hons)">Song Writing and Cabaret Performance BA (Hons)</a></h3>
<div class="reviw_rating">
<div class="rate_new"><span class="cat_rat">OVERALL UNIVERSITY RATING</span> <span class="ml5 rat rat5"></span> 
<div class="rw_qus_des">Tell us about your overall university experience so far.</div>
<p class="rev_dec">I started on the wrong course for me but was supported greatly in the transition to something better suited! All the stuff are so lovely and I feel truly cared for by my teachers. I have learned so much already and have been inspired from being surrounded by so much passion and talent. There are so many opportunities to play and create in a range of ensembles, and I am happy here. </p>
</div>
<div id="viewMore_1" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="rate_new"> 
<span class="cat_rat">Job Prospects</span> 
<span class="ml5 rat rat5"></span>
</div>
<div class="rate_new"> 
<span class="cat_rat">Course and Lecturers</span> 
<span class="ml5 rat rat5"></span>
</div>

<div class="rlst_wrap">
<h2><a href="/university-profile/university-of-chichester/5487/" onclick="viewProfileGaLogging('University of Chichester')" title="University of Chichester">University of Chichester</a></h2>
<h3><a href="/degrees/musical-theatre-and-arts-development-ba-hons/university-of-chichester/cd/55511108/5487/" title="Musical Theatre and Arts Development BA (Hons)">Musical Theatre and Arts Development BA (Hons)</a></h3>
<div class="reviw_rating">
<div class="rate_new"><span class="cat_rat">OVERALL UNIVERSITY RATING</span> <span class="ml5 rat rat4"></span> 
<div class="rw_qus_des">Tell us about your overall university experience so far.</div>
<p class="rev_dec">Would love more opportunities to do shows and workshops on the course </p>
</div>
<div id="viewMore_2" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="rate_new"> 
<span class="cat_rat">Job Prospects</span> 
<span class="ml5 rat rat3"></span>
</div>
<div class="rate_new"> 
<span class="cat_rat">Course and Lecturers</span> 
<span class="ml5 rat rat3"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd notice that div with class 'rlst_wrap' contains the rating, university name, review, course name etc.

Upon inspecting the page you'll see that this div is repeating itself 10 times, which is equal to the number of ratings per page.

You could find this element and loop through it to extract other information like, university's name, course name, ratings etc.

This code should work for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def get_rating_from_class(classes):
    """
    extract the rating from classnames
    ml5 rat rat5 -> 5
    """
    return classes.split('rat')[-1]


DRIVER_PATH = 'D://chromedriver/100/chromedriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)


# cookie accept dialogue box
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="cki_ftbtn"]'))).click()

# get review on the page
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="rlst_wrap"]')))
reviews = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="rlst_wrap"]')

# loop through review and extract university, course, and ratings
for review in reviews:
    # title = review.find_element(By.XPATH, 'h2/a').get_attribute('title')
    title = review.find_element(By.XPATH, 'h2/a').text
    course = review.find_element(By.XPATH, 'h3/a').text
    rating_class = review.find_element(By.XPATH, '(div/div/span)[2]').get_attribute('class')
    print(f'{title}\t{course}\t\t{get_rating_from_class(rating_class)}')
```